# mstsc /v /admin command in Remmina or similar rdp client in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rdp, mstsc

Sometimes we have to use this below command to use rdp to our old server 2003 domain.

```
mstsc /v:servername /admin
```

I have ubuntu desktop with Remmina and i can use normal RDP login for most of the time using Remmina gui.. but when i need to disable Remote Desktop Services client access licensing and force login, I use above command.

I'm not sure Remmina can do the same or do I have to use a different client or this is impossible. Just wish to take advice, please help. 
I've tried googling and found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/628371/how-to-run-linux-remmina-from-the-terminal), but not found exact thing what i look for.

Comment: Isn't the "Attach to console" in the Advanced tab what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often Im seeing below message, while trying to login to server 2003 ..

[image]

Then as its already suggested, by roaima , What i do is to use  "Attach to console" in the Advanced tab

[image]

Above option should be equal to below windows command

```
mstsc -v:servername /F -console
```

Attach to console" in the Advanced tab achieves much more similar to this switch /admin as well.... **(Actually /console switch has been replaced by /admin switch in later operating systems such as windows 7 ,  Server 2008 and Vista etc )**

[MSTSC /console is now MSTSC /admin](http://blogs.technet.com/b/peterfi/archive/2008/01/11/mstsc-console-is-now-mstsc-admin.aspx)

if you type mstsc /? in server 2003 command prompt you will see

this

[image]

and below is mstsc /? results for windows 7

[image]

Check below for more details..

[What is the /admin switch in Microsoft Terminal Services Client (MSTSC) for Windows 2008 and Vista?](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/what-admin-switch-microsoft-terminal-services-client-mstsc-windows-2008-and-vista)

[What exactly is the console session in RDP?](https://superuser.com/questions/21145/what-exactly-is-the-console-session-in-rdp)

https://superuser.com/questions/237626/what-is-the-significance-of-the-admin-switch-in-mstsc-exe

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-line-parameters-remote-desktop-connection#1TC=windows-7

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: What's the equivalent of `mstsc /admin` with Remmina?